# The type or namespace name 'ModelStateDictionary' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I did just upgrade a asp.net mvc2 project to mvc3 with this tool. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008
And that did work rather well,

how ever now I ran into an issue with the MVC3 project I have two error that states this: The type or namespace name 'ModelStateDictionary' could not be found.

Even though I am using System.Web.Mvc

[image]

Comment: Did you add the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace in your class?

Comment: Yup, I did add the Using System.Web.Mvc; How ever it seems to complain about the .Mvc that it does not exist on .Web

Comment: What is the version of the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly?

Comment: I've been trying with  2.0.0.0, 3.0.0.1 and 4.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to library package manager command line in visual studio and re-install the [Asp.Net MVC package(version 3)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/3.0.20105.1). it may solve your reference problem.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.20105.1
```